# kubernetes kompose up Unsupported env_file key

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, kompose

i am trying to migrate a docrized project to kubernetes, i have used Kompose to convert the project

`kompose --file docker-compose.yml convert`,

when i run `kompose up` after migrating the files 
i get this error

`$ kompose up
WARN Unsupported env_file key - ignoring

FATA Error while deploying application: k.Transform failed: image key required within build parameters in order to build and push service 'drkiq'`

.env file:

`SECRET_TOKEN=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
WORKER_PROCESSES=1
LISTEN_ON=0.0.0.0:8000
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://drkiq:yourpassword@postgres:5432/drkiq?encoding=utf8&pool=5&timeout=5000
CACHE_URL=redis://redis:6379/0
JOB_WORKER_URL=redis://redis:6379/0`

Dockerized project Link [here](https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/dockerizing-a-ruby-on-rails-application)!

any idea how to convert the .env file to a format that can be used with kubernetes kompose

Docker-compose file:

```
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.4.5
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: drkiq
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: yourpassword
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - drkiq-postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  redis:
    image: redis:3.0.5
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    volumes:
      - drkiq-redis:/var/lib/redis/data

  drkiq:
    build: .
    links:
      - postgres
      - redis
    volumes:
      - .:/drkiq
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    env_file:
      - .drkiq.env
  sidekiq:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
    links:
      - postgres
      - redis
    volumes:
      - .:/drkiq
    env_file:
      - .drkiq.env
```

Comment: Please include the docker-compose.yml file.

Comment: @BMitch file added, than you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Kubernetes kompose supports `env_file` conversion from [Docker Compose 3.x](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) version as it's described in [Conversion matrix](https://github.com/kubernetes/kompose/blob/master/docs/conversion.md).

In Kubernetes you can use [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/) to store your environment variables from `env_file`. For `SECRET_TOKEN` variable, you can use [Secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) to hold your private and sensitive data.

You can also check other tools for conversion purpose like [compose2kube](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/compose2kube) or [k8s-env-gen](https://github.com/dhoer/k8s-env-gen).

According to the attached `Docker-composer` file and the error during the conversion process, I can assume that you missed image key value for `drkiq` and `sidekiq` services:

**Update:** docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '2'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.4.5
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: drkiq
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: yourpassword
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - drkiq-postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  redis:
    image: redis:3.0.5
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    volumes:
      - drkiq-redis:/var/lib/redis/data

  drkiq:
    build: .
    image: drkiq:tag
    links:
      - postgres
      - redis
    volumes:
      - .:/drkiq
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    env_file:
      - .drkiq.env
  sidekiq:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
    image: sidekiq:tag
    links:
      - postgres
      - redis
    volumes:
      - .:/drkiq
    env_file:
      - .drkiq.env
```

Comment: i added the image key value and i got an error `ERRO Could not parse config for project drkiq : Service 'drkiq' has both an image and build path specified. A service can either be built to image or use an existing image, not both. 
FATA composeObject.Parse() failed, Failed to load compose file: Service 'drkiq' has both an image and build path specified. A service can either be built to image or use an existing image, not both. 
`

Comment: @zewOlF You need to specify `version` parameter in your docker-compose.yml file to avoid mentioned error. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: i got this error i am not sure why is this `FATA Error while deploying application: k.Transform failed: Unable to build Docker image for service drkiq: Unable to build image. For more output, use -v or --verbose when converting.: The command '/bin/sh -c bundle install' returned a non-zero code: 139 
`

Comment: @zewOlF Try to run your project with `docker-compose up` in order to check consistency of the build objects and in case of issues capture logs.